# how to make it responsive please ? bootstrap - css -html

Tags: css, html, bootstrap-4, footer, responsive

im working on a portfolio website and i have a bug on my code, i want to put footer under card pricing. thank you.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/qYMvd.jpg

HTML :
FOOTER SECTION :

```
<footer class="footerP">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="small-footer col-12 col-lg-12">
                <div class="footer-title col-12 col-lg-6">
                    <h3>PASTEUR SERVICE STATION</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="footer-social hidden-md-down col-lg-6 text-right">
                    <ul id="menu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-facebook"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-twitter"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-google-plus-g"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">
                                <i class="fab fa-instagram"></i>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
        <div class="big-footer">

        </div>
    </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

CSS CARD :

```
.card{
max-width: 300px;
height: auto;
border-radius: 15px;
padding: 40px 20px;
margin: 0 auto;
box-shadow: 0 10px 15px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
transition: .5s;
overflow: hidden;
```

}

FOOTER CSS :

```
.footerP .small-footer{
width: 100%;
height: 40px;
background: #232323;
```

}

thank you guys for help.

Comment: post the html too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the whole thing in a footer tag and assign a class of "footer" (the Bootstrap default class).

```
<footer class="footer">
  <div class="container-fluid">
   <!--Rest of your code --!>
```

The default Bootstrap .footer will keep it full width and sticky to the bottom of the page.